# spring retry unit test

Tags: spring, junit4

I am using spring retry (http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/) in a maven project and I have the following unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class RetriableFileManagerTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("asset")
    private AssetResource assetResource;

    @Test
    public void testRetry() throws URISyntaxException {
        byte[] image = this.assetResource.fetchResource("name", "path");
        verify(assetResource, times(3)).fetchResource("name", "path");
        Assert.assertEquals("should be equal", "image", new String(image));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    public static class SpringConfig {
        @Bean(name = "asset")
        public AssetResource assetResource() throws Exception {
            AssetResource remoteService = mock(AssetResource.class);
            when(remoteService.fetchResource(anyString(), anyString()))
                    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Remote Exception 1"))
                    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Remote Exception 2"))
                    .thenReturn("Completed".getBytes());
            return remoteService;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to run the test it fails with

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ctp.cms.actions.handlers.repository.resources.AssetResource ctp.cms.actions.handlers.filemanager.RetriableFileManagerTest.assetResource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ctp.cms.actions.handlers.repository.resources.AssetResource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=asset)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ctp.cms.actions.handlers.repository.resources.AssetResource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=asset)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue, I had to move the `@Retryable` annotation to the interface that `AssetResource` implements and autowire this interface type to the unit test.

Comment: AssetResource was final class?

Answer (score 2):

Error message says

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [ctp.cms.actions.handlers.repository.resources.AssetResource] found
>   for dependency

How is `ctp.cms.actions.handlers.repository.resources.AssetResource` declared?

Do you have `@Component` `(@Service` or similar annotation on it?) Is this package enabled for `@ComponentScan` ?

Comment: AssetResource bean is declared in the application spring context xml which is not loaded by the junit test. The class itself has no @Component or similar annotation in it.

Comment: you must load context that declares AssetResource class. no need to load xml file for whole application, you could have test context just with AssetResource class (and dependencies of AssetResource )

Comment: Did this and now the assetResource bean is loaded from the xml spring configuration. However, its method is not mocked and included to the @EnableRetry annotation. I am following the example in https://github.com/bijukunjummen/test-spring-retry/blob/master/src/test/java/retry/SpringRetryDeclarativeTests.java

Comment: do you have  @EnableRetry on any context loaded by the test?

Comment: Yes, in the inner static class in the unit test (SpringConfig). I was expecting the AssetResource to be injected from this specific context (the inner static class) unless I am missing something.